# Changing access column labels via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, label, ms-access-2007, title

I have searched for solution for this problem for a while now and can't seem to find anything relevant. Is it possible to change column labels (titles) in table via VBA. The only way I find to do it is to create query based on table with parameters as SQL aliases. However it adds some more elements to my already complex data base, it is something I want to avoid. I do not want to change column names. Is there any solution to this problem or should I leave it as it is now?

Thanks for the time you took reading this and for answers!

Comment: If you mean changing column names dynamically on an ad hoc basis, I would strongly advise you not to do this.

Comment: As I wrote I do not want to change their names, just the way they are displayed to the user. I can do it manually by changing their title in table project tab. I want to know if I can do this dynamically.

Comment: I am afraid I do not quite get what you want. What is the table project tab? Are you working with forms?

Comment: If u eneter the table and choose project view you can change options of columns. One of the option is title (or label, I do not use english version so I dont new how it is translated). You can put there the label of the column that will be displayed when somebody opens the table. It will not change the name of the column, just the way it is displayed. I want to know if I can alter this property of the column via VBA.

Comment: If you want to avoid a query because it `[1][adds]` to your `[2][already complex database]`, all I can say is you must solve `[2]` and get busy with `[1]`.  The alternative is to experience trouble in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is what you want, but I am never greatly in favour of adding information to a table that could confuse future users.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Usage()
    SetProperty "Table1", "ID", "Caption", "This is an ID"
End Sub

Sub SetProperty(TableName As String, Fieldname As String, _
    PropertyName As String, PropertyValue As Variant, _
    Optional PropertyType As Variant = dbText)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim prp As DAO.Property

    On Error GoTo Err_Property

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set fld = db.TableDefs(TableName).Fields(Fieldname)
    fld.Properties(PropertyName) = PropertyValue

    ''Debug.Print fld.Properties(PropertyName)

    Exit Sub

Err_Property:

    ' Error 3270 means that the property was not found.
    If DBEngine.Errors(0).Number = 3270 Then
        ' Create property, set its value, and append it to the
        ' Properties collection.
        Set prp = fld.CreateProperty(PropertyName, _
            PropertyType, PropertyValue)
        fld.Properties.Append prp
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```